# finite number of zeros of a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose that $f$ is analytic on a region $D = \{|z|>R\}$, and the limit of $\vert f \vert$ at infinity exists. Show that $f$ is either the constant function $0$, or has only finitely many zeros.

I thought since the limit at infinity exists then Laurent seires of $f$ only contains the principal part plus a constant, but how do I proceed to show that this will only have finite zeros ?

Comment: By 'principal part' you mean the $z^{-n} $ terms?

Comment: yes exactly I mean those negative power terms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is false. Let $g$ be analytic in $\{z:|z|<\frac 1 R\}$ with in finitely many zeros but not identically zero. [There are many such functions. The zeros will necessarily accumulate near the boundary]. Let $f(z)=g(\frac 1 z)$. Then the hypothesis  is satisfied but the conclusion fails. An example of a function $g$ with stated properties is $g(z)=\sin( \frac {\pi} {\frac 1 R -z})$. It vanishes at the points $z=\frac 1 R -\frac 1 n$.

However, if $f$ is assumed to be holomorphic in $\{|z| \geq R\}$ (and $\lim_{z \to \infty} f(z)$ exists) then it can have only finite number of zeros. Note that $f$ is holomorphic in some open set $U$ containing $\{z:|z| \geq R\}$.  Once again define $g(z)=f(\frac 1 z)$ This is holomorphic in some open set containing $\{z:|z| \leq \frac 1 R\}$ . The hypothesis tells you that $g$ has  a removable singularity at $0$. The extended function is holomorphic in an open set containing $\{|z| \leq \frac 1 R\}$ so it can have at most finite number of zeros (unless it is identically $0$) The same is true for $f$.

Comment: Can you provide a more specific example?

Comment: @Andrew I have now given an example in the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I understand your example might work, however I'm not rly sure if the function in your example has a limit at infinity? I was thinking about the function sin(z)/z but someone pointed out the limit doesn't exist at infinity:  https://www.quora.com/Who-could-answer-the-limit-of-sin-z-z-as-z-approach-to-infinity-where-z-is-complex-not-real

Comment: @Andrew The limit of $f$ at $\infty$ is same as limit of $g$ at $0$. This limit exists and the value is $g(0)$. In the example I have give this limit is $\sin (R\pi)$.

Comment: @Andrew $\frac {\sin \, z} z$ does not work as a counterexample because $|\frac {\sin (i n)} {i n}| \to \infty $ as $ n\to \infty$. My example is $\sin (\frac {\pi Rz} {R-z})$ and this works.

Comment: But what if we change the condition such that the funcion is analytic in the region ||≥ ? Will the statement be valid then?

Comment: @Andrew In that case the statement is true.

Comment: Is there any way to prove it? I tried to discuss the two cases when there is an infinite convergent sequence of zeros (then by identity theorem the function is constantly zero) and case when the sequence does not converge, but I'm stuck here

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'll think about it carefully

Comment: @Andrew See the second part of my answer now.

Comment: Can you explain again why did you say {||≥−}? Shouldn't it be +r instead of minus? Also in order to show g has a removable singularity at 0 did you use the Riemann Theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity#Riemann's_theorem) on removable singularity?

Comment: @Andrew I should have said 'some open set containing $|z| \geq R$. I have corrected the answer. Yes, I did use Riemann's Theorem.